# Yochlol [Shapechanger feature] Hit Point cases

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, shapeshifting

Yochlol have a Shapechange feature which reads:

> Yochlol can use its action to **polymorph** into a form that resembles
>   a female drow or giant spider, or back into its true form. **Its
>   statistics are the same in each form**. It reverts to its form when it
>   dies.

If a Yochlol has taken damage and it polymorphs into a different form, does it heal back to full hit points similar to the Druid's Wild Shape ability?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No

Druid's Wild Shape replaces the HP of the druid with the new forms'. In the case of the Yochlol, the HP statistic is maintained as seen by your emphasis.

From Wild Shape (*emphasis* mine):

> When you transform, you assume the beast's *Hit Points* and *Hit Dice*.

Comment: Might be worth adding that the word "polymorph" has no special meaning in 5e: you have to look to the specific text of the effect that causes is.